# Airflow connection string format?

Tags: airflow

I couldn't find the documentation for Airflow connection strings.  Here's an example list of them from my Airflow UI.
[image]

In particular, I couldn't find the format for `aws_default`, and only by reading the source code did I find that it takes an URL of the format `http://<aws_access_key>:<aws_access_secret>@<aws_host>`.

Does anyone know where this information is documented?  Thanks

Comment: The information is documented https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-environment-variables